# Unable to find match with yq in for loop

Tags: bash, yaml, yq

I have a yaml file called teams.yml that looks like this:

```
test:
  bonjour: hello
loop:
  bonjour: allo
```

I want to loop over an array and get itsvalues matching a key in the yaml. I have tried `yq e 'keys | .[] | select(. == "test")' .github/teams.yml` and it returns `test` whereas `yq e 'keys | .[] | select(. == "abc")' .github/teams.yml` returns nothing which is enough to get the information I am interested in.

The issue is that, when using the same logic in a for loop, yq returns nothing:

```
#!/bin/bash

yq e 'keys | .[] | select(. == "abc")' .github/teams.yml # Prints nothing
yq e 'keys | .[] | select(. == "test")' .github/teams.yml # Prints 'test'

ar=( "abc" "test" "xyz" )
for i in "${ar[@]}" # Prints nothing
do
  yq e 'keys | .[] | select(. == "$i")' .github/teams.yml 
done
```

What explains the lack of output in the for loop?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `yq` with the loop variable set in the environment, and use `env` within `yq` to read environment variables. See also the section [Env Variable Operators](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/env-variable-operators) in the manual.

```sh
ar=( "abc" "test" "xyz" )
for i in "${ar[@]}" # Prints nothing
do
  i="$i" yq e 'keys | .[] | select(. == env(i))' .github/teams.yml 
done
```

---

Another way could be to import the (preformatted) array from the environment and just make the array subtractions within `yq` (saving you the looping and calling `yq` multiple times):

```sh
ar='["abc","test","xyz"]' yq e 'env(ar) - (env(ar) - keys) | .[]' .github/teams.yml
```